# Issue Creating Dynamic Signature For Twitter API

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-oauth

I had initially hardcoded the signature and timestamps just to get routes set up. Now I am going back to set up the dynamic signature for users and I am getting an error from the Twitter API.

```
{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}
```

I have played around with the signature and the auth header and still the same error response.

```
    // Creates the timestamp in milliseconds
const timestamp = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000).toString();

// Percent encodes base url
const encodedBaseURL = encodeURIComponent(
  `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token`
);

// Percent encodes params
const encodedParams = encodeURIComponent(
  `oauth_callback="http://localhost:3000/auth/twitter"&oauth_consumer_key="${process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY}"&oauth_nonce="${timestamp}"&oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1"&oauth_timestamp="${timestamp}"&oauth_version="1.0"`
);

// Combines the percent encoded string to match https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/creating-a-signature requirements
const oauth_signature = `POST&${encodedBaseURL}&${encodedParams}`;

// Creates signing key for hashing
const signingKey = `${encodeURIComponent(
  process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET
)}&`;

console.log("sig", oauth_signature);

// Hashes string with signingKey then returns base64 string
const hashedSignature = createHmac("sha1", signingKey)
  .update(oauth_signature)
  .digest("base64");

console.log("hash", hashedSignature);

// Https request options object
const twitterOptions = {
  hostname: "api.twitter.com",
  port: 443,
  path: "/oauth/request_token",
  method: FETCH_METHODS.POST,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `OAuth oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Ftwitter",oauth_consumer_key="${process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY}",oauth_nonce="${timestamp}",oauth_signature="${hashedSignature}",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="${timestamp}",oauth_version="1.0"`,
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue. You have to percent-encode the signature in the Authorization header.